# Visa for spouse accompanying a Scientific-Researcher in France

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, france

I am a Indian, finishing my Phd in Netherlands. I am married to an Indian who at the moment lives in India.

I have been offered a scientific research position (PostDoc) at a university in Paris starting March 2017. I checked online, and it seems that I should apply for 'Long Stay Visa for Scientific-Researcher'. I will be applying to the French embassy in Brussels (which does Visa work for Netherlands) in the coming days.

My main question: (1) Can my wife simultaneously apply for a spouse visa in India as well. If this is possible, what documents would she need?

As far as I understand, I need a 'Convention d’Accueil' (hosting agreement) from the employing university for my visa application. (2) Does my wife need this document for her visa application as well?

(3) Would she need any other documents from my employer?

(4) A final question regarding my own visa application. The hard copy of my marriage certificate is with my wife. Would I need this hard copy for my visa application at Brussels, or would scanned documents be sufficient for the application?

I tried to contact the French consulate in Brussels, but they do not accept phone calls for Visa purposes. I have written them an email but I am hoping that someone here can provide me with some insight.

Comment: This should probably be migrated to [expats.SE](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A post-doctoral position is a job, based in the country in question, so I'd check very carefully if that is the right visa. It doesn't sound it to me.

Comment: @Relaxed How do I migrate to expat.SE? Should I ask the same question again there?

Comment: @CMaster I tried to check online and this is the French visa for scientific researchers. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @CMaster I can clarify that, it's definitely the right visa. If you read French, you can verify that here: http://www.campusfrance.org/fr/page/le-visa-de-long-sejour-scientifique-chercheur, http://www.immigration.interieur.gouv.fr/Immigration/L-immigration-professionnelle/La-carte-de-sejour-temporaire-portant-la-mention-scientifique-chercheur and http://www.immigration-professionnelle.gouv.fr/proc%C3%A9dures/fiche/scientifiques-chercheurs

Comment: @UPS You and I can't do it and you don't need to do anything, I have asked moderators to take care of it. It might take a few hours, though.

Comment: I'm on this visa in France. It is the correct visa, OP is right. And OP can bring his wife with him. However I didn't bring any spouse with me, so I don't know beyond this. And also, this does belong on expats.

Comment: And you'll need all originals before you apply for the visa. You don't need to give them the originals, but the officials at the embassy will need to see them to verify that your photocopies are the actual thing.

Comment: @Relaxed OP *could* do it himself, by copying the question and pasting it there, then closing this one.